# No Such Algorithm : AES/GCM/NoPadding

Tags: java, aes-gcm

I'm trying to use AES/GCM/NoPadding within the Java code for decryption. Below is the code

```
public static byte[] decryptRes(final byte[] sessionKey, final String symetricKeyAlg,
        final String pkiProvider, final String encXML, final String msgRefNo)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
        BadPaddingException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    final StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder(msgRefNo);
    strBuilder.append("0000");
    final SecretKeySpec symmKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(sessionKey, "AES");
    final Cipher symmCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding", "BC");
    symmCipher.init(2, symmKeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(strBuilder.toString().getBytes()));
    final byte[] xmlData = symmCipher.doFinal(base64Decode(encXML));
    return xmlData;
}
```

Now, when this code is invoked, it throws

> Exception : java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: No such algorithm: AES/GCM/NoPadding

and not

> NoSuchProviderException.

The necessary providers is already added but I still get the above mentioned exception.

> Java version 7 being used.

Jars Used :

1. > bcprov-jdk15to18-169.jar
2. > bcprov-ext-jdk15to18-169.jar

The above jars are available in the application lib folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could finally resolve the above mentioned issue. There is absolutely no issue with the code provided. However, I was facing the issue because of the BouncyCastle jar not registered as Service Provider.
Updated the **java.security** file under

**>$JAVAHOME/lib/security/java.security**

Add the below line if the provided is not added

> security.provider.<#>=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider

**Follow the link for details** :

https://makeinjava.com/install-bouncy-castle-provider-configuring-java-runtime-example/